# конкатенация строк в экзеле

Tags: vba

скопировал данные с htm файла в excel. после того как сделал разъединение ячеек вышла таблица, где записи, которые должны были разместиться в одной ячейке, разошлись на 2-3 ячейки вниз. Можете подсказать какой-либо код VBA который мог объединить ячейки вместе. Простую формулу конкатенации применить не могу, именно потому что, количество ячеек, которые нужно собрать различается. от 2 до 5. Можно сделать вручную, но общее количество строк около 5 тысяч.

Comment: Примера нет, как помогать?

Comment: я могу выложить файл для примера?

Comment: Вставь в вопрос CSV-текст, который можно скопипастить в Excel и получить твой файл, например.

Comment: *Простую формулу конкатенации применить не могу, именно потому что, количество ячеек, которые нужно собрать различается. от 2 до 5.* Но ведь есть же какой-то признак, позволяющий понять что пора начинать собирать с нуля? например, непустая ячейка другой колонки... вот на неё и надо ориентироваться. Типа `C2=ЕСЛИ($A2=""; СЦЕПИТЬ(C1;B2); B2)`

Comment: [вот так](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCJXT.png)

Comment: спасибо за формулу. логику того, что нужно сделать вы поняли правильно. Такой момент можно чтобы строки собирались в строке где стоит номер, тогда потом можно будет вставить значения и удалить лишние строки. и есть какой либо вариант сделать это через VBA?

Comment: >> *есть какой либо вариант сделать это через VBA?* Вариант есть,но примера нет. Где писать?